# How to use mapreduce in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce

I have the following code in python:

```
from pymongo import Connection
import bson

c = Connection()
db = c.twitter

ids = db.users_from_united_states.distinct("user.id")

for i in ids:
    count = db.users_from_united_states.find({"user.id":i}).count()
    for u in db.users_from_united_states.find({"user.id":i, "tweets_text": {"$size": count}}).limit(1):
    db.my_usa_fitness_network.insert(u)
```

I need to get all the users and find the register of each user where the number of `tweets_text` is equal to the number of times that it appears in the collection (meaning that this document contains ALL the tweets that the same user posted).
Then, I need to save it in another collection, or just group it on the same collection.

When I run this code it gives me a number of documents that is less than the `ids` number

I saw something about mapReduce but I just can't figure out how to use it in my case.

I tried to run another code directly on mongodb but it hasn't worked at all:

```
var ids = db.users_from_united_states.distinct("user.id")

for (i=0; i< ids.length; i++){
    var count = db.users_from_united_states.find({"user.id":ids[i]}).count()
    db.users_from_united_states.find({"user.id":ids[i], "tweets_text": {$size: count}).limit(1).forEach(function(doc){db.my_usa_fitness_network.insert(doc)})
}
```

Can you help me please? I have a huge project and I need help. Thank you.

Comment: db.collection.find() and db.collection.count() are async operations. Directly on mongo (javascript) you need to use the callback to wait for the result for the count before doing the find.

Comment: I am storing the count() value in a variable and then I perform the find()...

Comment: if my guess is right you want each user and its tweet count, ryt?

Answer (score 1):

```
[
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user.id",
            "my_fitness_data": {
                "$push": "$text"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "UserId": "$_id",
            "TweetsCount": {
                "$size": "$my_fitness_data"
            },
            "Tweets": "$my_fitness_data"
        }
    }
    ]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer but it is not what I am looking for. I need to group all the tweets of each user. I found this code and it works but I need to save it in another collection, do you know how can I make it?

`db.users_from_united_states_bkp_1.aggregate([{ $group : { _id : "$user.id", my_fitness_data: { $push: "$text" } } }])`

Comment: I've solved my issue with the $out parameter. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: that good!! I have edited the answer so that it helps other who look at this thread